# SQL Server Replication not able to use proxy

Tags: sql-server, proxy, replication

I have setup a replication publication through the SSMS wizard on a 2012 SP3 CU10 SQL Server, but the replication keeps on locking out the Replication Agent account. Looking at the SQL Agent replication jobs, they are failing with

```
Error authenticating proxy ####, system error: The user name or password is incorrect.)
```

I have done the following

- Selected from sysproxies and confirmed that the proxy is enabled.
- Restarted the SQL Agent after creating the replication publication.
- Added every login on the server as a principle of the proxy, with the exception of the sysadmins
- Used three seperate accounts to act as the replication Agent

Nothing has worked. Someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the suggestion to change the service account that the SQL Agent was running under, to a domain based account from a local account. This fixed the issue with the proxy and the replication was successful. I still don't understand why the local account cannot make use of a proxy.